# Shed Siding Clearance

Tags: siding, shed

I'm building a 12x20 shed pretty soon, and will likely put it on a concrete slab with treated sill plates bolted to the concrete.  The walls will be the standard 92 5/8 studs with 3" of top and bottom plates.  If I use 8' siding panels (the current plan...), the bottom edges will be at the top of the sill plates, leaving the edges of the sillplates exposed all the way around.  I'm sure that ground contact for the siding isn't desirable, so I guess the question is whether the sillplate exposure is normal and expected.  Is that the way it's supposed to end up?